# Travel from Mumbai to Toronto via long layover in Cairo

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, egypt

We are Indian citizens and are planning to travel by Egypt air from Mumbai to Toronto via Cairo. The layover is 14 hours in Cairo.

As per Egyptian Embassy, transit without visa is applicable if the layover is upto 12 hours.

do we actually need a transit visa for a layover of 14 hours?

Comment: Welcome to the site. What exactly is your question ? Please try to be specific

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to understand if I would need transit visa for Cairo. My flight is Mumbai - Toronto via Cairo(14 hours layover in Cairo). I have valid visa to travel to Canada.

Comment: We can't override the Egyptian government. If the Egyptian Embassy says you can only transit without a visa up to 12 hours, that's what the answer is.